# Cannot post a new document to db over http if the url string contains a "?" character

Tags: sql, database, rest, http, url

I am using a [HTTP api](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/OrientDB-REST.html) to POST new documents containing a url into the database via sql with this code:

```
http://localhost:2480/command/demo/sql/insert into clipboard4 set Name='test', url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnC6ONe5ZXM'
```

Everything works great, until I try to post a URL containing a "?" character. The db responds with this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing closed string character: ''', position: 73
```

I am new to sql, and I have not been able to find a viable solution. The solution must be somewhere in sql?

I have looked at encoding the characters with html encode. [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) as well as encodeURIComponent() methods. encodeURI does not encode "?" characters. And encodeURIComponent may contain a solution, but looks very complicated as it encodes to much characters. In addition, the URL saved into the document needs to be an exact replica of what I would see in the url bar. Not an html encoded url. I would prefer not to send a url with a encoded character, then have to go to the database and correct this.

If I cannot solve this here, I will try some google user groups.

Any ideas, suggestions? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you really sending SQL statements inside a request and just execute them on the server side? Never heard of SQL injection? Maybe have a look at http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: How about trying to encode the '?' character too?

Comment: The database is local, everything is local. Nobody but myself will be posting to the db. I dont anticipate any problems with SQL injection as I am the only one with access. As far as encoding the ? character, if encodeURI() method did encode it by default (which it doesnt) it would become "%3F". I would rather not save a url string like that. Which creates more work decoding it back. But maybe this is worth investigating.